# Using if logic in VSTS 2015 build definitions to specify if a build step is run

Tags: build, visual-studio-2015, build-process

I am creating a build definition in VSTS 2015 and have a series of build steps. Based on certain Variable values I have in my build definition set at queue time how can I make it choose to preform certain Build steps.

This Build definition, builds and packages the installers of about 15 different components and each component has it's own release definition. I am trying to make it so if at queue time the variable flagging componentA is set to true it will run the build step that calls the release definition of ComponentA

I haven't been able to find any information of adding logic to run a build step based on certain values